# What outdoor materials can be damaged by by ice?

Tags: maintenance, ice

I'm relatively new to this snow thing. I also have a new vinyl deck and paver stone walkway I'd like to take care of. I have a basic understanding of how water can get into things, freeze, and break them apart. I'd like to prevent this from happening.

For what materials should I worry about preventing ice damage?

Answer (score 2):

Ice/water can damage anything and everything.

A vinyl deck should be OK. Your pavers might heave a bit if water gets under them and freezes. But that's the great thing about pavers. Easy to fix come spring. (tamp it down or add more sand if it needs to be raised)

Answer (score 2):

My vinyl deck was damaged from icicles falling 2 stories off the house and onto the deck.  Probably not as much an issue for pavers, but the softer vinyl materal can be damaged.

Answer (score 2):

I would say the most important thing to do for ice at your house is to install frost-free sillcocks to prevent the lines from freezing and the pipes from bursting in your house.  I take the extra precaution of shutting off valves in the house and draining my sillcocks.